# jQuery UI Sortable and Draggable List Interaction Not Working Quite Right

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a recipe tracker tool for World of Warcraft players here: http://www.wowgeeks.com/tracker.php?item=recipes. I have three custom-designed lists: a "Have" list, a "Need" list, and the list of original items to choose from. I have the last list as a draggable, with its `connectToSortable` set to a class that the first two lists share.

HTML for the three lists:

```
<div class="sub-third">
    <h1>My Recipes</h1>
    <div class="tracker-list sortable" id="have-list">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="sub-third">
    <h1 style="color: #f90;">Recipes I Need</h1>
    <div class="tracker-list sortable" id="need-list">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="sub-third">
    <h1 style="color: #eee;">Add Recipes</h1>
    <div class="tracker-list" id="add-list">
        <div class="tracker-item" id="itemid_123">
            <a class="tracker-icon" rel="item=43509"><img class="wow-icon" src="/images/icons/small/inv_scroll_03.jpg" alt="Icon" /></a>
            <p>Bad Clams</p>
        </div>
        <!-- ETC... -->
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the JavaScript for the draggable/sortables:

```
$(function() {
    $('#add-list .tracker-item').draggable({
        connectToSortable   : '.sortable',
        helper              : 'clone'
    });

    $('#have-list, #need-list').sortable({
        connectWith : '.tracker-list',
        cursor      : 'move',
        revert      : true,
        placeholder : 'ui-state-highlight',
        update      : function() {
            var order = $(this).sortable('serialize');
            order += '&userid=1&itemtype=Recipes&charid=0';
            //alert(order);
        }
    });

    $('.tracker-list, .tracker-item').disableSelection(); // So dragging doesn't accidentally select any text

    $('#have-list, #need-list').sortable('refresh'); // Refresh the lists
});
```

For some reason, after I drag an item from the 3rd list to the 1st list one or two times, it suddenly refuses to cooperate. The items in the 3rd list suddenly become un-draggable. But dragging items from the 3rd to the 2nd list works just fine. You can try the link above and test it out for yourself. Can anybody tell me what the problem might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#add-list .tracker-item').draggable({
    connectToSortable   : '.target-list',
```

You're connecting the third list only to the second list here. If you make add the target-list class to the first list you can then drag from third to first.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my code at the same time you replied. It was an error in copying the code. I fixed it and you can see it above.

Comment: I visited your site and was able to reproduce the bug. Now that you have made the connectToSortable   : '.sortable' modification the bug no longer exists.

Comment: I'm still seeing it. Did you try dragging more than one item from the gray list to the blue list box? It works fine the first time, but after it is dropped, the gray list no longer acts as a draggable UI object.

Comment: Ah, indeed. What's the dimension plugin being used by? That's where the first exception gets thrown.

Comment: It's being used by a Tooltip plugin I use on a few other pages. If I remove the call to that script... what do you know, it fixes it. I'll see if I can do without Dimensions; if not, I'll find another tooltip plugin. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, that sucks. I've used the http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html a few times to great success.